# How to remove full path name and add comma for the first two columns created?

Tags: batch-file

I am struggling to edit the below command line to only give the name of the file name instead of the full path name and file. I would also want a comma straight after that and another comma straight after the second column (which is the created date done in do, as its a delimited notepad file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _SRCDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Source
set _DSTDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Target

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.cos"') do (
type "!_SRCDIR!\header.txt" > "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
call :handle_file "!_SRCDIR!\%%f" "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
)
goto :eof

:handle_file
set _TMPVAR0=%~t1
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`"findstr /n ^^ %1"`) do (
    echo %%g
    set "_TMPVAR1=%%g"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "_TMPVAR1=!_TMPVAR1:*:=!"
    echo.%~1 !_TMPVAR0: =-! !_TMPVAR1!>> %2
    endlocal
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: So you are still working on **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980s?

Answer (score 0):

[untested, since you give no indication of the data involved and present a confused list of the outputs you need]

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _SRCDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Source
set _DSTDIR=C:\Users\hyea\Desktop\Testing\Target

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d "!_SRCDIR!\*.cos"') do (
 type "!_SRCDIR!\header.txt" > "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
 set "_TMPVAR0=%~tf"
 set "_tmpvar0=!_tmpvar0: =-!"
 for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%g in (`findstr /n ^^ ""`) do (
  echo(%~nf,!_TMPVAR0!,%%h>>  "!_DSTDIR!\%%f"
 )
)
goto :eof
```

which should insert the header then copy each line, including blank lines, prefixing each line with

filenameonly`,`the filedate/time (with spaces replaced by `-`)`,`linebody